# Synopsys VCS message severity change from error to warning

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

I want to change the severity of the message from error to warning.

I'm currently experiencing the below error:

```
Error-[IPC] Illegal high conn for port connect
```

Please let me know if any switch is available for this in the VCS compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the 2023 version of VCS on SolvNet, the VCS User Guide documentation states that you can change the severity of the message from error to warning using a configuration file, but this is only possible for *some* error messages.  This is specified in the section named "Error/Warning/Lint Message Control".

Refer to the documentation for the version of VCS that you are using.

In the configuration file, you can add a line like:

```
-error=noIPC
```

Note:

> Not all error messages are downgradable. If you enter an error message
> ID for a non-downgradable error message, you receive a different error
> message indicating that it is not downgradable.

There are also options to disable the display of messages for some errors.